# Taps gesture not working?

Tags: c#, android, ios, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have the following page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Taps"
             x:Class="Taps.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:AboutViewModel x:Key="AboutViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource AboutViewModel}">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowHiddenTextCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="5" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Image HeightRequest="77" WidthRequest="115" />
            <Label Text="MyApp" FontSize="48" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Text="My name" />
        <Label Text="1.0.00" />
        <Label Text="Platform" />
        <Label TextColor="Blue" Text="Open Stackoverflow">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenStackOverflowCommand}" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>

        <Editor IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding HiddenText}" IsVisible="{Binding ShowHiddenText}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And view model:

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Taps {
  public sealed class AboutViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public string HiddenText { get; } = "Some text";

    private bool showHiddenText;
    public bool ShowHiddenText {
      get => showHiddenText;
      private set => Set(() => ShowHiddenText, ref showHiddenText, value);
    }

    private RelayCommand showhiddenTextCommand;
    public RelayCommand ShowHiddenTextCommand => showhiddenTextCommand ?? (showhiddenTextCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ShowHiddenText = true));

    private RelayCommand openStackOverflowCommand;
    public RelayCommand OpenStackOverflowCommand => openStackOverflowCommand ?? (openStackOverflowCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"))));
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to show the hidden Editor when tapping on the stack panel the required number of times.  It does seem to work on my Moto G running Android 5.1, but doesn't work in an iPod Touch and not in UWP.

The label tap seems to work fine on all platforms, so I'm not sure what is going on.  How do I get the `ShowHiddenTextCommand` to fire after the specified number of taps?

I'm using the latest Xamarin.Forms and MvvmLight library.

Comment: Is it working if you set the `NumberOfTabsRequired` to 1 or 2?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg It seems like numbers greater than 2 don't work.  I guess I can implement a counter manually as a work around.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/), more than two taps is allowed, but it must be within the set period of time. I've tried looking at the [source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) but no luck trying to see what that time is. Try tapping **really** fast.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot For UWP I'm actually running on my desktop, so tapping/clicking fast enough is not the issue.  I am doing more research on this as it seems like its not even consistent between VS2017 and 2015; on 2015 it seems NO taps are registered.